# JFrame class not working in Main

Tags: java, swing, jframe, extending

I'm trying to write a Java program that declares a JFrame class and creates an object of that class in the main. For the life of me I cannot get the JFrame title, JPanel, and JButtons to appear when I create the "MyButtons" object in the main. All I get is a blank JPanel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class MyButtons extends JFrame
{
    public MyButtons()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyButtons");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);     
    }      
}

class TestMyButtons
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       MyButtons go = new MyButtons();
       go.setSize(200,75);
       go.setLocation(200,300);
       go.setVisible(true);
       go.setResizable(true);
       go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }   
}
```

Comment: as far as I know , If you define a class inside another class, one of them has to be public which is gonna be the first one?

Comment: @KickButtowski I'm gussing, they are are actually separate classes

Comment: @MadProgrammer if they are together, what I said is right?

Comment: @KickButtowski The "second" class can't be `public`, but I'm not sure how you would run `TestMyButtons`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you extend JFrame so you don't need to create another JFrame instance at constructor. Simply add `panel` to `MyButtons` which already inherited `JFrame`.

```
public MyButtons(){

    //JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyButtons"); Commentted this
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    //frame.add(panel); And this

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");

    panel.add(b1);
    panel.add(b2); 
    add(panel); // Add panel to MyButtons frame    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're making two instances of `JFrame`, `MyButtons` and `JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyButtons");`, to which you are adding all your components...

It's very rare that you would ever need to extend directly from a top level container like `JFrame`, instead, extend from something like `JPanel` and then add that to an instance of `JFrame` instead...

`MyButtons`...

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class MyButtons extends JPanel {

    public MyButtons() {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        add(b1);
        add(b2);
    }
}
```

`TestMyButtons` ...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

class TestMyButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MyButtons());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how? do you have any opinion about my comment?